# Tool to get BlackBerry log

Tags: blackberry

For the iPhone there is a console tool for printing Nslog.  For Android there is logcat.  For Palm there is putty.

Is there any tool like this to print the log for BlackBerry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "javaloader.exe" command line tool, which comes with the developer tools (I think) can be used to extract data from the device's event logger.  You can also press the Alt-lglg key sequence on the device (or simulator) home screen to see log entries locally (and copy them).

If you're trying to actually send data to the event log, look up the JavaDocs for the EventLogger class.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the methods octo explained, you can also just use "System.out.println" and as long as the simulator or device is connected to a debugger (JDE or Eclipose in debug mode), you will see the output in the debug window.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a Linux System and converting an Android App to Blackberry. I am using the Toolset available here:

https://developer.blackberry.com/android/

```
    d.) Start ADB Proxy to connect a device or VMWare simulator through ADB to an Android development environment of your choice 
>bin\blackberry-adbproxy [<device IP address>] [-detect] [-gui] [-password <device password>]
or
>bin\blackberry-adbproxy -gui
```

This tool allows me to get Logging Info from my Blackberry like I would get from an Android Device.

Comment: This answer is relevant for BlackBerry apps that run on Android, I think the question came from the era when BlackBerry apps were developed in their version of J2ME and used BlackBerry APIs, tooling, etc.