# Is there a way to get the stack trace of an exception in form of a String in Blackberry?

Tags: debugging, blackberry, java-me, crash, trace

I want to log the stack trace of exceptions into a file. Is there a way that I can get the stack trace in form of a `String`, or somehow make `ex.printStackTrace()` print the trace into a stream or a file? I know that there is [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069066/get-current-stack-trace-in-java) to do this in Java standard edition, but I want this in Blackberry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BlackBerry only provides stack traces when you catch a Throwable.   So you should be able to use printStackTrace and friends if you change the catch type.

**EDIT** 
Sorry, I misread your question -- thanks for the comment.   No, there's no way to get the stack trace in a String object.   There is a support forum thread from January 2010 that covers this - [Stack Trace Capture (sorely needed)](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Stack-Trace-Capture-sorely-needed/td-p/415098).  Nothing has changed since then.

If you need this for development, [you can extract the event log from the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022433/tool-to-get-blackberry-log), which includes stack traces. But that doesn't help sort out production issues.

Comment: I understand that I should use `catch (Throwable ...)`, though what I want is to have the stack trace as a `String` so I can write it into a file for example. `ex.printStackTrace()` is only capable of printing it to the debug output console.