# How to implement a global uncaught exception handler for blackberry?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, crash-reports, blackberry-jde

Hello im trying to add a module to my app so whenever the app crash i can send usefull information to my server/mail to track the error. This info could be the model, Blackberry so version, **stacktrace** or at least the exception that was unhandled in my app. Obviously i put try/catch where ever i think an error could happen but as human we can make some mistakes :) and is hard to simulate all the issues that a mobile could suffer.

I already implement it on Android wich was more easy since it has a **UncaughtExceptionHandler** class, also in Android there is a pretty awesome tool to do this if you don't want to do it yourself [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). So i want to know if there is a way to do so on Blackberry and if it isn't what is the usual work around for this on this plataform.

Im working on blackberry from Blackberry 5.0 to 7.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackberry has not such mechanism like `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` on Android or `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` on iOS.

I recommend to use a proposal described in [this post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/J2me-Uncaught-exception-handler/td-p/2044549#)

```
public class MyApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            new MyApp().enterEventDispatcher();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exeption
        }
    }
}
```

If you use own `Thread` subclasses or `Runnable` implementations, you should also `catch` all Exceptions in `run()` method

P.S. Also there is [no way to get stack-trace as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389758/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-stack-trace-of-an-exception-in-form-of-a-string-in-bla) you only able to print it to stdout

Comment: Hello after some research i just used what you just recommended. Since we can't have the stacktrace i thought that i could have a string that i will concat in every listener so i can know what was the user doing when the exception got catched, but i have to this carefully since this string can get too big !! . Anyways Thank you for your answer and have a nice day!.