# Blackberry crash log collection

Tags: blackberry, java-me, crash-dumps

Is there a mechanism to collect all the stack traces of a BlackBerry application if I am doing OTA app delivery?

I believe Apple collects and gives us the crash logs, or you can extract them by connecting the iPhone to a dev machine and using XCode to read the crash logs. Is there an equivalent mechanism for the Blackberry?

If not, are there any libraries that can log all the exceptions and push them out to a server?

Answer (score 1):

Automated collection just isn't possible.  There's no way to get a stack trace in a String, which would be the first step of an automated crash handler.

There's a StackOverflow question just about getting the stack as a string:
[Is there a way to get the stack trace of an exception in form of a String in Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389758/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-stack-trace-of-an-exception-in-form-of-a-string-in-blac)

---

If you are doing development and can connect your computer to the device, you can get the event log or console output by using javaloader.exe.    JavaLoader has a pretty long help page which it displays if you run it without arguments.  You can find JavaLoader.exe in your Eclipse plugins folder, where the BlackBerry JDE is unpacked.

The StackOverflow question that mentions JavaLoader:
[Tool to get BlackBerry log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022433/tool-to-get-blackberry-log)

Comment: I'm worried about rolling it out our users and not having any stacktraces to debug errors that they get. What would be the standard practice in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to ask your users for stack traces, they will appear in the Event Log automatically (at least, for uncaught exceptions).  They can use ALT-LGLG from the device home screen (on devices with keyboards) to get into the Event Log, and then from there they can copy the day's events to the clipboard and paste into an email.

The biggest downside to this approach is that the event log is often larger than the clipboard can hold, so you won't get a full event log.

Comment: I don't really want to ask our users to do it, but I'm thinking about including a catch all clause and uploading them to a server. Will this work?

Comment: Yes but you won't be able to get a full stack trace - just the specific error that was thrown (and any information it might contain).