# How to log messages properly in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, logging

For example, in Android there's the `Log` class I could use for code like the following one:

```
android.util.Log.d(tag, msg);
```

Is there anything equivalent in BlackBerry (event logger)? If so, can you provide an example?

Comment: Searching stackoverflow for "+blackberry +log" turns up a number of very relevant questions.  Two stand out as already answering this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612034/blackberry-log-file 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439331/blackberry-console-output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were using the Java API, then you might use the Blackberry "EventLogger" class:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html

http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB05349

Comment: Yeah, RIM is completely screwed. I've interacted professionally with some of their executives, and they're a remarkably clueless bunch. Their only hope really is to pull a Nokia and start selling Windows phones.

Answer (score 0):

There is no helper class like Log (Android) in blackberry. You will have to make your own version of it.

If you want to log messages to the eventlogger in blackberry (accessible by pressing ALT+LGLG) , you can use the [eventlogger](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html) class