# How to read all logged information in a BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

How can we print a simple msg on Blackberry's equivalent of Android logcat? In Blackberry there is anything equivalent to Logcat that can display Log or `System.out.println` msgs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to get BlackBerry log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022433/tool-to-get-blackberry-log)

Comment: Searching on Stack Overflow for "blackberry log" turns up some nice questions that already have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [EventLogger](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html) API allows you to log messages to the device's system log. You can access the system log from the device's home screen by pressing ALT-L, ALT-G, ALT-L, ALT-G.

It is possible to filter the event log to display only the events logged by your application (select "Options" on the event log screen and check the boxes for your app).