# view Blackberry log

Tags: blackberry

In Android through Logcat we can see application debug output and logs. In Blackberry is there any thing like Logcat? If not then where we can see its debug output.

Comment: Searching for '+blackberry +logcat' turns up several duplicates of this question, among them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022433/tool-to-get-blackberry-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RIM API SDK there is [EventLogger](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EventLogger.html) class. Use it for logging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

above answer is good even though you can use system.out.println(string what you want to see in log list );
and you can see the output in blackberry simulator output console 
for example,

```
try{

}catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

when ever exception will come at that time you can see the exception details in the blackberry simulator output console